# 404 when requesting json file with Angular http

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have this code in my service

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Client} from "../clients/client";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";


@Injectable()
export class ClientsService {


  private clientUrl = './client.json';

  private headers = new Headers({ 'Accept': 'application/json' });
  private options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });

  private client : Client;

  constructor(private http:Http) {}

  getClient() : Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(this.clientUrl, this.options)
      .map(res => res);
  }
}
```

and in my component I'm calling it:

```
this.client = this.clientsService.getClient()
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

But I'm getting 404 error

[image]

But I have this `json` file in the same folder where my service is.

[image]

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the absolute path from your base path. Like, `path/to/Services/client.json`

Here's an example: https://plnkr.co/edit/60E2qb9gOjvkEAeR5CtE?p=preview

Comment: if I copy reference it's `src/app/Services/client' and If I enter that result is same. If I add .json at the end result is same

Comment: @gsiradze is your base folder src? How about `app/Services/client.json` ?

Comment: @gsiradze Glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you using angular-cli Keep the json file inside Assets folder (parallel to app dir) directory

In your case you need to create file like assets/client.json

```
return this.http.get('/client.json'))
    .map((response: Response) => {
        console.log("mock data" + response.json());
        return response.json();
    }
    )
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Note: here you only need to give path inside assets folder like assets/client.json then you need to write path like /client.json

If you using webpack then you need to follow above same structure inside public folder its similar like assets folder.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this code in file the **typings.d.ts**

```
declare module "*.json"
{ const value: any;
  export default value;
}
declare module "json!*"
{ const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

and simply import using `import * as data1 from 'path.json';`